# Return value of a function with a loop?

Tags: c++, function, loops, for-loop

I have the following code, however i am confused about several things:
Why is the sum inside the loop returning? why not the one outside?

or does the program return will return value encountered and ignore the rest?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int m(int n)
{
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i =1;i<=2;i++)
  {
    sum= sum + 10;
    return sum+3333; //returns inside loop
  }
  return sum-10;
}

int main()
{
  int n = 1;
  cout << m(n) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Returns exits the function

Comment: When the `return` keyword is encountered, the function *returns* to the calling code (in this case, to `main`).

Comment: So is it similary to break in this case? it will ignore the loop and go back to main?

Comment: Yes. Note that this also means the loop will only execute once. The `for` loop is a glorified `if (1 <= 2)` which is always true. Do not be surprised if the compiler discards the whole function and generates code for `cout << 3343 << endl;`

Answer (score -1):

Once the compiler will encounter return it will go back to main; so in this case it will return to main once it encounter it inside the loop